# How to download & display an image from ftp server

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ftp

(new to xCode and programming) I am trying to connect/download/save to variable and display an image in UIImageView from an ftp server. The code is below. Any help advice would be appreciated.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //sets label to notify user whats happening
    NSMutableString *labelString;
    labelString = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"Connecting"];
    [labelDymamic setText: labelString];

    //variable for ftp location
    NSString *ftpLocation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ftp2.bom.gov.au/anon/sample/gms/IDE00003.201011170430.gif"];
    //variable to recieve data
    NSMutableData *responseData;

    //loads ftpLocation into url
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:ftpLocation];

    //sets label to notify user whats happening
    NSMutableString *labelStringDownloading;
    labelStringDownloading = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"Downloading"];
    [labelDymamic setText: labelStringDownloading];

    //Connect to ftp
    self.ftpImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Icon.png"];
    self.labelDymamic.text = @"Receiving";
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    (void) [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: request delegate:self];

    //download image


    //save to variable


    //display to screen


    //sets label to notify application loading complete
    NSMutableString *labelLoadedString;
    labelLoadedString = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"Radar"];
    [labelDymamic setText: labelLoadedString];

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}
```

At the moment all that is displayed is a white screen with labelLoadedString variable "Radar".

Thanks
Allan

Comment: I believe that @Daij-Djan is meaning that you tagged this wrong. In future, please tag as "iOS", "objective-c", or something else similarly constructive. Although, this doesn't actually help answer the question, does it? ;)

Comment: I find it bad that 99% of ppl do this wrong ^^ sorry if I was too short :D (my answer should be more helpful)

Answer (score 1):

your url is wrong, its missing the SCHEME: ftp://

---

as for downloading:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//download
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * r, NSData * d, NSError * e) {
    //save
    UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:d];

    //display
    self.imageView.image = img;

    //sets label to notify application loading complete
    NSMutableString *labelLoadedString;
    labelLoadedString = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"Radar"];
    [labelDymamic setText: labelLoadedString];
}];
```

Comment: Thankyou so much it is now working. I will endeavour to tag any questions in the future. Thanks again Allan

Comment: :D glad I could help, happy new year :D

Answer (score 0):

After fixing your URL, which as mentioned appears to be incorrect, checkout AFNetworking (see https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking). There's a category on `UIImage` that will make your life a lot easier when dealing with loading images from remote locations (such as over http, https, ftp, you name it ;)

Here's an example from their overview:

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f, 100.0f)];
[imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://i.imgur.com/r4uwx.jpg"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder-avatar"]];
```