# Insert an image from ftp server in swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, server, ftp

I want to insert an image in my app coded with swiftui by using an ftp server but I don't see how to handle that.

At this moment I add an image like that :

```
AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "file:///Users/user/Library/Mobile%20Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Soft/apdemo/demo/src/Export/"+graph1+imageId+".png")) { image in
                    image.resizable()
                } placeholder: {
                    ProgressView()
                }
                .frame(width: 1050, height: 75)
                .background(Rectangle().fill(Color.white))
                .border(Color.black, width: 1)
```

And I would like something like that :

```
AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "ftp://user:password@host:port/path")) { image in
                    ...
```

I have already seen these post but I don't really understand how does it work. Does someone has any real examples ?

[How to download & display an image from ftp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107619/how-to-download-display-an-image-from-ftp-server)

[file downloading from ftp server in iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8612724/file-downloading-from-ftp-server-in-ios-application)

[How to download FTP file in swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51625557/how-to-download-ftp-file-in-swift-3)

Comment: What, exactly, is your question? How to format the FTP URL?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yes I want to know how can I format what is inside the AsyncImage to display the picture which is indicated by the ftp path

Comment: What do you mean by "format what is inside the AsyncImage"? Your `AsyncImage` is formatted properly.

Comment: my 2 cents worth is, do not use ftp, it is not secure and has no place 
in SwiftUI apps. I doubt very much that you will be able to use the ftp URL you show the way you want it.
See this apple site, for official and pertinent info on ftp:  https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/97469